# VBA enabling text and combo box in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'd like to make a text box (Text28 hereafter) and a combo box (combo43 hereafter) enabled when another combo box (Combo26) takes the value "Resolved"

So this is the code, written in VBA, that should do that :

```
    Private Sub Combo26_AfterUpdate()

If Combo26.Value = "Resolved" Then
    Me.Text28.Enabled = True
    Me.Combo43.Enabled = True
Else
    Me.Text28.Enabled = False
    Me.Combo43.Enabled = False

End If

End Sub
```

Unfortunatly, nothing happens when I try it. Would you have a idea ?
Thx

Comment: Please post the rowsource for Combo26

Comment: @DataWriter SELECT [StatusList].[ID], [StatusList].[Status] FROM StatusList;

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) -- put a break point in the sub and check `Combo26.Value` - it will be an ID, not the string you expect.

Comment: @Andre how can I check Combo26.Value, or Combo26.Column(0)? thx

Comment: With `Debug.Print`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pulling two columns as your row source (as indicated in your comment above), it looks like the first one that is displayed is the ID. You should target the second column to do your comparison, e.g.,

```
If Combo26.Column(1) = "Resolved" Then
  ...
```

That works for me!

```
Combo26.Column(0)
```

will give you the ID.